# how to create "angular friendly" ajax adapter instance for AbstractDataServiceAdapter

Tags: breeze

we are currently trying to get breeze and angular working together... one thing we are trying to avoid is having to manually call $scope.apply() after every remote procedure call... i am trying to write an "ajax" adapter instance that will use angular's $http service... the problem however is that angular's http service does not expose the xhr object... i think, not sure this is a problem because i believe breeze expects this object to be present, and even exposes it to the client... really the only thing i want to achieve is being able to call $scope.apply() AFTER breeze comes back from the server and does all of its work, including calling client callbacks... i would like to do this without making changes to the breeze source code, and i know breeze is very extensible... but it's also a very large library and i am having trouble pinpointing where the interception point is... does anyone have any advice??? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly identified the issue.  Right now Breeze does expect an XHR and angular does not return one.  We have a feature request that should make it in one of the next few releases to allow you to wrap angular's http service as a 'breeze' ajax adapter.

For now though: (*the rest of this is speculative and untested, but the general idea should work*), your best bet might be to create a decorated version of the existing 'ajax' adapter. i.e. something like.

```
 var origAjaxCtor = breeze.config.getAdapter("ajax");
 var newAjaxCtor = function () {
    this.name = "newAjax";
    this._origAjaxCtor = new origAjaxCtor();
 }
 newAjaxCtor.prototype = new oldAjaxCtor(); // to delegate all other methods
 newAjaxCtor.prototype.ajax = function (settings) {
    settings.success = function((data, textStatus, XHR) {
       // call the original success code
       settings.success(data, textStatus, XHR);
       // followed by your custom scope code.
       // ...do your scope apply here...    
    });
    // perform the actual ajax call - this will call your custom success method from above.
    this._origAjaxCtor.ajax(settings);
 }
 // register the new adapter
 breeze.config.registerAdapter("ajax", newAjaxCtor);
 // make this adapter the default
 breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("ajax", "newAjax", true);
```

Comment: thank you... unfortunately the above work around did not work... it looks like the "real" success callback delegates the final user code callback to Q, which appears to execute async some time AFTER... so even though my "wrapper" success callback calls scope.apply AFTER it calls the "real" success callback, it is still BEFORE the user code has executed... for now i am going to manually call scope.apply... i will wait for breeze to natively support angular... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As of Breeze 1.4.4, we now support an angular ajax adapter that uses $http.  See the 1.4.4 release notes for more details.

For your specific issue, if you use the angular ajax adapter's setHttp method you can have Breeze use your $http instance internally.